# SSAS Mesure Source Table

Tags: ssas

I'am new on SSAS cube and i want to find the source table name of a mesure .
I cheked on properties but find nothing;[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjvmE.png)

How can I do to find the table that provide this mesure with data please .
Thanks for help

Comment: If an answer solved your question, you should mark it as the correct answer by clicking on the gray checkmark beside it, turning it green.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your screen shot:

1. `Cash Register Discrepancy Amount` is the measure you are looking for
2. `Cash Register Discrepancy Amount Local` is the underlying measure

Now, you need to look for the source of the underlying measure, i.e., `Cash Register Discrepancy Amount Local`

[image]

Using the Adventure Works sample, the Measure `Internet Gross Profit` uses 2 underlying measures `Internet Sales Amount` and `Internet Total Product Cost`.

[image]

So, now we will search of this measure, first in `Calculation`, then in the `Cube Structure`. We can see the measure under the "Internet Sales", we can now go to the Properties to find the underlying table and column.

[image]

Good luck

Comment: Hello  Subbu , that was very helpful , thanks a lot :)